# Put views on a background VideoView

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with a VideoView.

I have to use a VideView as background and I need to have some views on this videoView.

I use a similar code in my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".Login"
    android:alpha="0.9">

    <VideoView
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/VideoView">
    </VideoView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run this example I can't see the video. I need to call the method

> videoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);

to display this video.

But in this way (when I call this method) I can't see the others components that they are overlapped on my videoView.

Some suggestions for this issue?

Comment: tried simple FrameLayout?

Comment: @pskink yes, I tried also with FrameLayout...

Comment: try this: http://pastebin.com/xTVeTfV4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <VideoView android:id="@+id/surface_view"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            ></VideoView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try my paste?

Comment: I would add a sentence that emphasizes you added `fitsSystemWindows` because I had to scroll back and forth for a while trying to find the difference.

Comment: I'm Sorry but I think that the most difference is the use of LinearLayout as container and RelativeLayout